# Rails remote form submitting multiple times with 'enter'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, remote-forms

I have a form on a page that is a single input field. I would like the user to be able to hit enter to submit the form. Unfortunately, the form gets submitted multiple times when `enter` is used to submit. I know the form is being submitted multiple times because there are multiple POST requests sent to the server. It happens in both development and production and it only happens sporadically.

```
= form_for thing, remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_field :name, placeholder: "hit enter to submit"
```

If I add a `f.submit` to the form, it will only submit once.

This is Rails 5 with `turbolinks` and `jquery_ujs` included in the `application.js` if that makes any difference.

**UPDATE**

I haven't been able to reproduce after making some changes.

I suspect the issue had to do with `jquery_ujs` being loaded multiple times on the page. This was due to `turbolinks`. More precisely, due to the fact that I was including all of my javascript in the `body` tag. `turbolinks` suggests adding your javascript files in the `head` tag. Since doing so, I have not been able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Why not use a hidden submit button?

Comment: @trueinViso After removing turbolinks, I haven't been able to replicate it. I found that jquery_ujs was sometimes being added twice on the page, due to turbolinks, thus causing the multiple submit actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using turbolinks, it's important that you add event handlers using the correct method. Do not place any Javascript in your HTML body tag. Use the turbolinks documentation to determine which events you need to hook into to add your own event handlers or make other transformations of page elements.

Current version of turbolinks: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events
Older version of turbolinks: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#events

The current version also has some [recommendations on making your document changes idempotent](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent), which I would do for adding event listeners as well.

Comment: Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Another case with such symptoms is using `rails-ujs` and `jquery_ujs` simultaneously. For my observations if `rails-ujs` goes before `jquery_ujs` in application.js everything is ok, but twice submitting on ajax-forms emerged in another case.